# Find difference in 2 tables / recordsets MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables in MySQL DB (A and B)
Both have very similar structure since table B has records that are inserted with all data each time user changes his data in table A to have full history of changes. Column Lastupdate is INT type and keeps time of update in UNIX timestamp format
So let’s say tables have records like that:

```
TableA
Id  User_id Name1   Name2       Lastname    Lastupdate
1   12     John     Alexander   Smith       1405594757
2   27     Marry    Ann         Poppins     1405594877
3   51     Jean     Claude      VanFist     1405594677


Table B
Id  User_id Name1   Name2       Lastname    Lastupdate
1   12      John    Alexander   Smit        1405594747
2   27      Marry   Ann         Poppins     1405594757
3   51      Jean    Claude      VanFist     1405594757
1   12      John                            1405594727
1   12      John    Alex                    1405594737
3   51      Jean                VanFist     1405594757
```

For each record from table A I would like to see comparison with the most current record of table B (basing on Lastupdate) with the information which field was changed

So for user_id = 12 I would have something like

```
Id  User_id Name1  Name2                    Lastname                Lastupdate
1   12      John   Changed name2:Alexander  Changed lastname:Smith  1405594757
```

I was trying something like that

```
SELECT if(u1.name1 <> u2.name1, CONCAT("Changed: ",u1.name1), u1.name1) 
FROM tableA   u1,tableB u2
WHERE u1.user_id = 7433 AND u2.user_id = 7433
```

But it seems not to be right way please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should indicate what field values changed as well as what they were and what they became:

```
select a.user_id,
       case when a.name1 <> b.name1 then concat(b.name1,' changed to ',a.name1) else null end as name1_chg,
       case when a.name2 <> b.name2 then concat(b.name2,' changed to ',a.name2) else null end as name2_chg,
       case when a.lastname <> b.lastname then concat(b.lastname,' changed to ',a.lastname) else null end as lastname_chg
  from tablea a
  join tableb b
    on a.user_id = b.user_id
 where b.lastupdate = (select max(x.lastupdate)
                         from tableb x
                        where x.lastupdate < a.lastupdate and x.user_id = a.user_id)
```

Comment: @HamidAlaei thanks, missed that part of the date sub

Comment: Thanks both of You with minor tweak - user_id as relation thats exactly i was looking for